# Particuler website is not being opened in IE

Tags: windows

I have been facing an issue in IE as it's not opening particular website. It's return with error "internet explorer cannot diskplay the webpage". However, I'm able to open that website in firefox and other browser. I have tried below mentioned things but still no luck.

(1) Checked the website on différent servers but same error
(2) Change the TLS and SSl value as per vendor requirement but no luck 
(3) for testing purpose, I re-installed IE 9 ...same
(4) reconfigure internet option (like delete cookies ,added site in trusted zone etc, same)
(5) But same website is working in users local computers (windows 7) but its not working in windwos 2003 and 2008

Please suggest that how can i get past of this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling IE Enhanced Security?

Comment: I didn't try that.. as I can replicate issue on another servers as well. I'm not sure whether it will sort the issue or not.

Comment: Try it and reportback

Comment: Just to be sure: *"I'm able to open that website in firefox and other browser"* refers to the very same computer where IE gives the error, right? And I assume other HTTPS sites open just fine in IE? And can't you give us the website URL? Now it's really too specific for you alone, I feel, and that's not what Stack Exchange is for.

Comment: yeah, On same computer i can open URL on different browers..I'm a bit skeptical about url sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly site is probably just not IE Compatible...  unfortunately a lot of developers don't always check all 3 browsers when developing web pages.

IE has been buggy since IE 5.0 and every version it seems to get just a little worse.  Sites can even be fine in one version of IE and not another.  Honestly it's why I had to install Chrome on 150 PC's and remote every one to setup default settings my boss wanted.

If you are on a domain you can remote install chrome on all the computers to reduce your work a bit.  Get with whomever is developing the site and tell them which version of IE your using and see if they can help.

Comment: Site in question is being opened domain users local computer IE (version 9.0)

Comment: Isn't Windows 7 IE 10? Web page is quite possibly in new version of HTML 5 vs HTML 4.  It is easier to program in but I don't know if IE 9 can read.  Still possible that it is just not working in IE 9 vs IE 10 (Windows 7) IE 11 (Windows 8).  Windows 2003? You mean XP & Vista?  

Officially XP is discontinued and no longer updated.

Comment: Once again I'd look up Creating Domain installation package for Chrome.

Comment: https://www.google.com/work/chrome/browser/ is the web site I found  looking for Google Chrome Standalone Enterprise MSI.